# Seeking Microsoft Access Count Distinct Alternatives Referencing Current Record With Multiple Tables

Tags: ms-access

I have the following tables of which most irrelevant columns have been excluded for simplicity:

First: Table "Counsellors" with the columns ID, Counsellor_Name

Second: Table "Clients" with the columns ID, Client_Name, Client_Type, Rate, Counsellor (Which references a counsellor from the counsellors table)

Third: Table "Appointments" with the columns ID, Client(Which references a client from the clients table), Appointment_Date, Canceled_Or_No_Show, Canceled_By_Staff, BC

Each counsellor can have any number of clients, each client can have any number of appointments

The below query currently works to give me a list of counsellors, with the columns containing counts I want based on the data given

```
SELECT 
    Counsellors.Counsellor_Name,
    Count(IIf(Clients.Client_Type = 'Single Adult', Appointments.ID, NULL)) AS AppointmentsSingleAdult,
    Count(Appointments.ID) AS TotalAppointments,
    Count(IIf(Appointments.Canceled_By_Staff = TRUE, Appointments.ID, NULL)) AS CancelByStaff,
    Count(IIf(Appointments.Canceled_Or_No_Show = '1' AND Appointments.Canceled_By_Staff = FALSE, Appointments.ID, NULL)) AS CancelByClient,
    Count(IIf(Appointments.Canceled_Or_No_Show = 'ns' AND Clients.NSP_Rate = 0 AND Appointments.Canceled_By_Staff = FALSE, Appointments.ID, NULL)) AS NSByClient,
    Count(IIf(Appointments.Canceled_Or_No_Show = 'ns' AND Clients.NSP_Rate <> 0 AND Appointments.Canceled_By_Staff = FALSE, Appointments.ID, NULL)) AS NSPaidByClient,
    Count(IIf(Appointments.BC = TRUE, Appointments.ID, NULL)) AS BCCount
FROM
    Counsellors INNER JOIN (Clients INNER JOIN Appointments ON Clients.ID = Appointments.Client) ON Counsellors.ID = Clients.Counsellor
GROUP BY
    Counsellors.Counsellor_Name;
```

I am attempting to add a column to this query that gives the count of unique clients the counsellor has appointments with in the date range (date range currently just always, I can add the date between where clause after)

I've originally attempted this with "`COUNT(DISTINCT Clients.ID) AS UniqueClientsInDateRange`" however access doesn't support having distinct inside of count, so I've tried some workarounds such as

`(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Appointments.Client FROM Appointments INNER JOIN Clients ON Clients.ID = Appointments.Client WHERE Appointments.Client = Clients.ID GROUP BY Appointments.Client )) AS UniqueClientsPerCounsellor`

`(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Clients.ID FROM Clients WHERE Clients.Counsellor = Counsellors.ID)) AS UniqueClientsPerCounsellor`

however with these methods access doesn't seem to be able to reference the current record's counsellor to give me the data for each counsellor and instead prompts me to manually enter it or says I'm not including the given expression.

Thank you in advance for any expertise that can be shared by those more well versed in MS Access!

Comment: while grouping is the wrong time to count each counselor's unique clients because each counselor can occur many times and you get counselor occurences * total unique clients.  Since each query is just a new table you can feed your current query as a subquery to another.  See here: https://www.geeksengine.com/article/access-distinct-count.html  But in Access I prefer saving intermediate queries rather than making one big query.  The intermediate tables help when debugging a year later and       turns complicated queries into many simpler steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build and save a query object that returns distinct count of clients from appointments that will provide counsellor ID:

Query: CountClientsDistinct

```
SELECT CD.Counsellors.ID, Count(CD.Clients.ID) AS CountDISTINCT
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Counsellors.ID, Clients.ID FROM Counsellors 
      INNER JOIN (Clients INNER JOIN Appointments 
      ON Clients.ID = Appointments.Client) ON Counsellors.ID = Clients.Counsellor) AS CD
GROUP BY CD.Counsellors.ID;
```

Join that query to your original query:

```
SELECT Counsellors.Counsellor_Name, 
Count(IIf(Clients.Client_Type='Single Adult',Appointments.ID,Null)) AS AppointmentsSingleAdult, 
Count(Appointments.ID) AS TotalAppointments, 
Count(IIf(Appointments.Canceled_By_Staff=True,Appointments.ID,Null)) AS CancelByStaff, 
Count(IIf(Appointments.Canceled_Or_No_Show='1' And Appointments.Canceled_By_Staff=False,Appointments.ID,Null)) AS CancelByClient, 
Count(IIf(Appointments.Canceled_Or_No_Show='ns' And Clients.NSP_Rate=0 And Appointments.Canceled_By_Staff=False,Appointments.ID,Null)) AS NSByClient, 
Count(IIf(Appointments.Canceled_Or_No_Show='ns' And Clients.NSP_Rate<>0 And Appointments.Canceled_By_Staff=False,Appointments.ID,Null)) AS NSPaidByClient, 
Count(IIf(Appointments.BC=True,Appointments.ID,Null)) AS BCCount, 
Max(CountClientsDISTINCT.CountDISTINCT) AS CountClientDISTINCT
FROM (Counsellors INNER JOIN (Clients INNER JOIN Appointments ON Clients.ID = Appointments.Client) 
      ON Counsellors.ID = Clients.Counsellor) 
      INNER JOIN CountClientsDISTINCT ON Counsellors.ID = CountClientsDISTINCT.ID
GROUP BY Counsellors.Counsellor_Name;
```

This will get more complicated if you apply filter, such as for a date range. Both queries will need the same filter.